Consistency in event sourcing
How to maintain consistency when using Event Sourcing? We are using Event Sourcing to work with balance, so we don't store current state in database. I have following scenario:

Lets assume I have balance 100$
I send two events to withdraw 100$, we are assuming that they happened simultaneously, so when they replayed events to check if there is enough money to withdraw 100$, they got positive response.
Send event to add 100$ to balance
I end up with 0 balance, but at some point I was able to withdraw more then I have and to have negative balance.

How can I prevent this? Since we don't use any table to store current state, how can we apply lock?
Addition:
I use Axon framework for event sourcing, maybe someone knows if there is some built in mechanism for this case and knows how it works?

Just checking whether this is a typo: "I send two events to withdraw 100$". Are you sending events, or commands?


How can I prevent this? Since we don't use any table to store current state, how can we apply lock?

The usual answer in CQRS/ES is that you are "locking" the history of changes (aka the event stream) when you try to extend it with new information.
So the flow of code for your example would usually look something like

Lock the history
Compute the balance from a locked copy of the history
Compare the withdrawal to the balance
if the withdrawal is permitted:

add new events to the history
save the changes to the history


release the lock


A variation you will sometimes see:

Fetch an UNLOCKED copy of the history
Compute the balance from the unlocked copy of the history
Compare the withdrawal to the balance
if the withdrawal is permitted:

add new events to the history
compare and swap the new history into place of the old



This sort of implementation normally comes with a retry loop, so that a second thread that loses the "compare and swap" race gets another chance to process its message.

Could this problem be solved on a infrastructure level? Aggregate's events often have version. So two simultaneous commands for withdrawal result  with two events with the same version. RDBMS event store would prevent storing two events with the same version for the same aggregate.

With the Axon Framework you don't need to be worried about it. As all changes should be done via commands, in this case targeted to an aggregate. Since all messages to an aggregate have a sequence number, it will always be consistent. Even when you have multiple instances, and just done a deployment, one of the application messages will fail to persist, and never be part of the event stream.

If I understand correctly, you need optimistic locking.
Not sure with Axon framework, but with Marten framework available for .Net users aren't allowed to step on each other's toes.
Ensuring this through current version of aggregate, when storing your event the version that you have must match current version available of the event stream. If not, then someone tapped in already meaning your data is stale and your request is rejected with a concurrency problem.
